# Java - Convert bytes from stream (with offset) to integer

Tags: java

I have stream of bytes, which I got by using getInputStream() method from socket. How to read 1 or 2 bytes from this stream with offset **n** and convert them to integer. 
Thanks!

Comment: To get an offset, you must read all the bytes before them.  You can't randomly access a stream from a socket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use `DataInputStream` which allows you to read primitive types:

```
DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(...your inputStream...);
int x = dis.readInt();
```

**UPD:** More specifically, you could use the code of `readInt()` method:

```
    int ch1 = in.read();
    int ch2 = in.read();
    int ch3 = in.read();
    int ch4 = in.read();
    if ((ch1 | ch2 | ch3 | ch4) < 0)
        throw new EOFException();
    return ((ch1 << 24) + (ch2 << 16) + (ch3 << 8) + (ch4 << 0));
```

<strike>**UPD-2:** If you read 2-bytes array and sure, that it contains full integer number, try this:</strike>

```
    int value = (b2[1] << 8) + (b2[0] << 0)
```

**UPD-3:** Pff, full method for doing it:

```
public static int read2BytesInt(InputStream in, int offset) throws IOException {

    byte[] b2 = new byte[2];
    in.skip(offset);
    in.read(b2);

    return (b2[0] << 8) + (b2[1] << 0);
}
```

Comment: also i want to specify how much to read - 1 or 2 bytes for integer

Comment: Thanks a lot, it works. Why if i write 
`System.out.println( read2BytesInt(in,8));
System.out.println( read2BytesInt(in,8));`
output is 96 and -1, not 96 and 96?

Comment: because first `in.skip()` causes moving to your `offset` position, and next invoking of it causes to move `offset*2` position. P.S. Unfortunately, AFAIK, in `SocketInputStream` you can not return to the start position.